# Azure: quickly change branch used on continuous deployment (github)

Tags: azure, github, continuous-deployment, azure-git-deployment

I have a webapp on Azure that is connected to github to do continuous deployment. Is there any quick way to change the branch it is connected to or I have to disconnect and then connect again to select the new branch?

The problem is that Azure has a bug somewhere that when I disconnect I can only connect again without an error, after 15 or 30 minutes of disconnecting...

Comment: what kind of error? Once you successfully disconnect, you should be able to setup CI again.

Answer (score 12):

Try go to your scm site "https://{site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net"

Debug Console -> Navigate to D:\home\site\deployments

Edit settings.xml and change to your desire branch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
    <deployment>
        <add key="branch" value="master" />
    </deployment>
</settings>
```

Comment: After doing that, is there any command or way in there to manually tell azure to update the website? the only way i found is to go to azure portal and hit sync on continuous deployments but I was looking for a quicker way :)

Comment: @AlfaTeK try:
`    az login  
    az webapp deployment source sync -n <your-site-name>`

Answer (score 1):

Using the [xplat-cli](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/) you can do:

```
azure site repository <yourbranch>
azure site repository sync
```

Comment: in azure-cli (2.0.44), it's more like  
`
az webapp deployment source delete -n <your-site-name>  
az webapp deployment source config -n <your-site-name> --repo-url $url --branch <your-new-branch> --git-token <your-git-token> --manual-integration  
az webapp deployment source sync -n <your-site-name>`

Comment: but it seems to be very buggy, probably @Xiaomin Wu answer is more suitable